# Angular patchValue does not work inside a loop. Why?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

To set values that I get from a server to an user form I use `pathValue` method, but if I do this line by line, work:

```
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'first_name': userData['first_name'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'last_name': userData['last_name'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'address': userData['address'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'city': userData['city'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'province': userData['province'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'postal_code': userData['postal_code'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'phone': userData['phone'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'birthdate': userData['birthdate'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'card_id': userData['card_id'] });
    this.userDataForm.patchValue({ 'email': userData['email'] });
```

But if I do this in a `forEach`, It does not work. `userDataForm` is a `FormGroup` var:

```
var items = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'city', 'province',
      'postal_code', 'phone', 'birthdate', 'card_id', 'email']
    items.forEach(item => {
      this.userDataForm.patchValue({ item: userData[item] });
    })
```

And I don't know why this happens. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change from `{ item: userData[item] }` to `{ [item]: userData[item] }` to use **Computed Property Names**:

```
var items = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'city', 'province', 'postal_code', 'phone', 'birthdate', 'card_id', 'email']
items.forEach(item => {
  this.userDataForm.patchValue({ [item]: userData[item] });
})
```

To know more about Computed Property Names:-

- http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames
- https://tylermcginnis.com/computed-property-names/

Though you don't need to iterate over the object's property to patch the value in the form, you can directly patch the whole object into the form:-

```
this.userDataForm.patchValue(userData);
```

Comment: Nice! I thought that `.pathValue(userData)` doesn't works because I have more data that I want to set but seems like only set the availables form keys. So, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because `item` is not resolved to iterator variable but is threated as plain key in object construct.